# (R): Calculate quantile by unique row value unification

Tags: r, aggregate, quantile, unification

I have a df like this:

```
> df<-data.frame(Client.code = 
c(100451,100451,100523,100523,100523,100525),dayref = c(24,30,15,13,17,5))
> df
    Client.code dayref
1      100451     24
2      100451     30
3      100523     15
4      100523     13
5      100523     17
6      100525      5
```

It is a one-year distribution of payments period from issue.

Usign this data above and given a df2 like this:

```
   Client.Code    Days
1  100451          16
1  100523          16
1  100460          35
```

As i have enough data for a reasonable quantile prob. calculations.I will like to know how to build a loop for assing to every row in this df2 of days a quantile according with the first df.

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(df)[, quantile(dayref) , .(Client.code)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Quantile = quantile(dayref)), Client.code]
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Client.code) %>%
   summarise(Quantile = list(quantile(dayref))) %>%
   unnest
```

Comment: It works. But not really useful, probably because my question was not good enough. It is posible with a given vector to asignate a quantile based on past distribution. Thanks

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodríguez  Can you please update your question nor create a new question if you have different condition

Comment: @ÁlvaroRodríguez  You can do something like `setDT(df)[, as.list(quantile(dayref)), Client.code][df2, on = .(Client.code =Client.Code)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
tapply(df$dayref, df$Client.code, quantile)
```

You can specify specific percentiles by adding a vector of them

```
tapply(df$dayref, df$Client.code, quantile, 1:19/20)
```

You may need to formulate like this

```
tapply(df$dayref, df$Client.code, quantile, probs = 1:19/20)
```

And you can add na.rm = TRUE as another argument if you might have NAs

Comment: It is a great solution. I have two questions related i´m figuring out, if interested: 1) how to write this array in xlsx. 2) a loop that could express the quantile associated with a given vector of numbers, more writeable